# Unable to Connect to HFSQL Server using OLE DB Provider using c#

Tags: c#, encryption, oledb

I am a C# developer currently building a Blazor Server Side application. I am trying to connect to a remote HFSQL database using the OLE DB provider to retrieve some data.

Here's the code snippet I am using to establish the connection:

```
public async Task<ResponseModel<List<string>>> TestConnection()
        {
            try
            {
                var connectionString = this.configuration["ConnectionStrings:ERPConnection"];

                using (var connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    await connection.OpenAsync();

                    DataTable tables = connection.GetSchema("Tables");
                    List<string> tableNames = new List<string>();

                    foreach (DataRow row in tables.Rows)
                    {
                        string tableName = (string)row["TABLE_NAME"];
                        tableNames.Add(tableName);
                    }

                    return new ResponseModel<List<string>>()
                    {
                        Data = tableNames
                    };
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return new ResponseModel<List<string>>()
                {
                    Error = new ErrorModel()
                    {
                        Code = 500,
                        Message = e.Message,
                    }
                };
            }
        }
```

The connection string in my configuration file is structured as follows:

```
"ERPConnection": "Provider=PCSoft.HFSQL; Data Source=YourHFSQLServer:YourPort; User ID=YourUserID; Password=YourPassword; Initial Catalog=YourDatabase; Extended Properties=\"Language=YourLanguage;Encryption=aes256;\""
```

Despite this, I'm still receiving an error message that the user is not authorized to connect to the database with an unencrypted connection. The error suggests that this authorization can be granted by the server administrator or via the HFSQL Control Center.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to solve this issue or alternative NuGet packages that could offer a secure connection to the HFSQL database?

Thank you for your help!

I've attempted to use the connection string directly as given in the HFSQL documentation. I've also tried adding extended properties to the connection string such as specifying the Language and Encryption algorithm, following the format recommended by the documentation.

I was expecting the connection to be established and for my code to return a list of table names from the database. However, each attempt results in an error message about unauthorized connection due to lack of encryption.

By providing such information, you give other users a clear idea of the steps you've taken to solve your issue, which can help them guide you more effectively towards a solution.